# Cloud Service - Building and deploying

Tags: web-applications, struts, cloud-hosting

Lets say I need to deploy a cloud service which provides features such as: upload files to server, download files from server and mail service for users.

I came across some technologies like apache struts, and JSP which can be used. Will they help me to build a cloud service and offer that in my own server?

My own server will be my laptop: which has 200 GB hard disk, uses windows 7 OS and I have installed Apache Tomcat in it.

Answer (score 0):

Before you go any further I suggest you stop and look more into web hosting generally.  Running anything off a laptop, especially one running Windows is a very bad idea for all sorts of reasons.